# SSH fingerprints not matching

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, macos

- host_a is macOS
- host_b is Ubuntu
- host_b is in known_hosts on host_a
- host_a is not in known_hosts on host_b

I've changed the fingerprints and trimmed some output for brevity but otherwise this is the sequence of events.

At some fairly random times, I try to ssh to host_b (in known_hosts) and I get a remote host warning.

```
me@host_a:~ $ ssh host_b                
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:9rxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNI.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:6
Host key for host_b has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Then, immediately I try again and it works:

```
me@host_a:~ $ ssh host_b
Last login: Sat Feb 11 11:49:59 2023 from 10.0.1.50
me@host_b:~$
```

Then I try ssh back to host_a (not known)

```
me@host_b:~$ ssh host_a
The authenticity of host 'host_a (10.0.1.50)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:9rxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNI.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? ^C
me@host_b:~$ exit
```

The strange thing is, the host_a fingerprint is the same one it was saying host_b identified itself as on the first attempt.

Back on host_a I try and check the fingerprints:

```
me@host_a:~ $ ssh-keyscan host_b | ssh-keygen -lf - 
...
256 SHA256:7gxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOA host_b (ED25519)
...
me@host_a:~ $ ssh-keyscan host_a | ssh-keygen -lf - 
...
256 SHA256:9rxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNI host_a (ED25519)
...
```

Running ssh-keyscan on localhost or 127.0.0.1 as opposed to host_a yields same fingerprints.

This only happens quite randomly, if I don't ssh to host_b for maybe 10-15 minutes then first attempt I get the warning that the fingerprint from the remote host mismatches (and its always actual host_a's fingerprint!)

I am fairly confident there is nothing rogue on my home network but what could be causing this?

Comment: If I read correctly, you try to first ssh to `host_b` and after that to `host_b.lan`? What output gives a keyscan on `host_b`?

Comment: Ah apologies, but the output is the same with/without the local suffix (ie host_b or host_b.lan). I had changed my real hostname to host_b and forgot to include the suffix originally, I will edit it.

Comment: @chrism Could it be that the IP address for `host_a` may be changing over time? This would explain why the fingerprint presented by `host_b` sometimes matches the fingerprint for `host_a`, and why you sometimes see the warning message when connecting to `host_b`.

Comment: No the IP isn't changing, it's assigned by my router, but that would imply a and b were getting the same IP and then there would be all manner of other issues if that was happening